# Find the bilinear transformation which maps $z=(1, i, -1)$ respectively into $(w=i, 0, -i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> Find the bilinear transformation which maps $z=(1, i, -1)$ respectively into $w =(i, 0, -i)$

**My try:**
Here, $w_1=i$, $w_2=0$, $w_3=-i$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=i$, $z_3=-1$
$\text{As the formula states,}$
$$\begin{align}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}&=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&\implies\frac{(w-i)(0+i)}{(w+i)(0-i)}=\frac{(z-1)(i+1)}{(z+1)(i-1)}\\
&\implies\frac{(w-i)i}{(w+i)(-i)}=\frac{(z-1)(i+1)^2}{(z+1)(-2)}\\
&\implies-\frac{w-i}{w+i}=\frac{(z-1)2i}{(z+1)(-2)}\\
&\implies\frac{w-i}{w+i}=\frac{(z-1)i}{z+1}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies\require{cancel}\frac{w-\cancel{i}+w+\cancel{i}}{\cancel{w}-i-\cancel{w}-i}&=\frac{i(z-1)+z+1}{i(z-1)-z-1}\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&\implies w=i\frac{(z-1)i+z+1}{(z-1)i-(z+1)}\\
&\implies w=\frac{i(z+1)-z+1}{i(z-1)-z-1}\\
\end{align}\\
$$
Now, I can't understand how to shape this equation like $w=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Please help.

Comment: You lost a minus sign after $2 w/(-2 i) =\ldots \,$. To get a simpler form, divide the numerator and denominator by $-1 + i$. Or consider that $-w(-1/z) = w(z)$ should hold, therefore the point which is mapped to $\infty$ is $-i$ and $w = k (z - i)/(z + i)$.

Comment: @Maxim my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get $\omega=\dfrac{(i-1)z+i+1}{(i-1)z-(1+i)}$.

It is important to remember that here $a,b,c,d$ are *complex* numbers.

Comment: Are you sure? In my book it is telling a, b, c, d are constants. Just confirm it and I will accept.

Comment: Yes.  I'm sure.  They are constant complex numbers.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you 