# Find the bilinear transformation which maps $z=(1, i, -1)$ to $w=(i, 0, -i).$ Also, find the image of $|z|\leq 1$ under the transformation.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value, conformal-geometry

> Find the bilinear transformation which maps $z=(1, i, -1)$ respectively to $w=(i, 0, -i)$. Also, find the image of $|z|\leq 1$ under the transformation

**My try:**
Here, $w_1=i$, $w_2=0$, $w_3=-i$, $z_1=1$, $z_2=i$, $z_3=-1$.
According to the formula,
$$\begin{align}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}&=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&\implies\frac{(w-i)(i)}{(w+i)(-i)}=\frac{(z-1)(i+1)}{(z+1)(i-1)}\\
&\implies-\frac{w-i}{w+i}=\frac{(z-1)(2i)}{(z+1)(-2)}\\
&\implies\frac{w-i}{w+i}=\frac{iz-i}{z+1}....(i)\\
&\implies-\frac wi=\frac{z(i+1)+(1-i)}{z(i-1)-(1+i)}\\
&\implies w=\frac{z(1-i)-(i+1)}{z(1+i)+(i-1)}\\
\end{align}\\
$$
Now, from eq.(i) we get,
$$\begin{align}\\
&\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{w-i}{iw-1}\\
&{\begin{aligned}\\
\implies\require{cancel}\frac{z-\cancel{1}+z+\cancel{1}}{\cancel{z}-1-\cancel{z}-1}&=\frac{w(i+1)-(i+1)}{w(1-i)+(1-i)}\\
\end{aligned}\\}\\
&\implies-\frac z2=\frac{w-1}{w+1}.\frac{\cancel{2}i}{\cancel{2}}\\
&\implies z=\frac{2i-2iw}{w+1}\\
\end{align}\\
$$
As, $|z|\leq 1$
$$\begin{align}\\
&\therefore\left|\frac{2i-2iw}{w+1}\right|\leq 1\\
&\implies\left|\frac{2i-2iu+v}{(u+1)+iv}\right|\leq 1\\
&\implies 4(1-u)^2+v^2\leq(u+1)^2+v^2\\
&\implies 4-8u+4u^2\leq u^2+2u+1\\
&\implies 3u^2-10u+3\leq 0\\
&\implies(3u-1)(u-3)\leq 0\\
\end{align}\\
$$
But, in my book it is written that the transformation maps to the right half of w-plane. Which is correct?

Comment: The  conclusion $ 2i-2i(u+iv)\leq u+iv+1$ is wrong because you removed the absolute value signs – that is the *same error* as in your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781558/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Oops! Sorry. I have edited my answer. But, still it doesn't match with my book's answer. Just, confirm it which is correct.

Comment: There is [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3776789) a mistake when multiplying by $-i$, and you're rederiving a form which is more complicated than necessary.